# Running a PHP file 24x7 on heroku. Is that possible?

Tags: heroku, firebase, cloud

I'm having a PHP file which has some JS in it. I run a script on this file which will check if the date on a firebase database matches with the current date and if not update a few values. So I want this PHP file to run 24x7. I am completely new to heroku. Is it possible to do this on heroku or is there any other simpler solution ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. You can set a `worker` process in your `Procfile` that will run a non web based process. In that PHP script you can set a timer to perform this action daily, and if were to crash for whatever reason, Heroku would restart the process.

Here's an explanation of how they work: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing